# What should we name our chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

We have a [chatroom](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/artificial-intelligence). At the moment it doesn't really have a name. Other sites' chatroom names include:

- Super User's "Root Access"
- PPCG's "The Nineteenth Byte"
- Blender's "The Renderfarm"
- Pets' "The Litterbox"
- Travel's "You Are Here"
- Aviation's "The Hangar"

So, what should we call ours?

While we're at it, what should we name our resident feed bots (Main and Meta)?

Comment: Do we have a winner here? I'd like solving the halting problem here :-)

Comment: @EricPlaton I think we should wait until just before we graduate, then put all the suggestions for the names of each bot into a polling service like strawpoll (to avoid the FGITW effect).

Answer (score 15):

### **The Singularity**

I probably don't need to explain that :-)

And for the bots, how about Daneel and Giskard?

Answer (score 8):

## Turing Testing Room

A play on the term "Turing test" (an examination of how well a machine mimics natural conversation with a human): tests taken by human students are usually administered in a testing room.

Questions on the main site are currently posted to the ticker, so we don't see the username, but if that's changed, it could be called **[Multivac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivac)** after the computer from some of Asimov's stories. We could call the meta bot **[Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer))**.

Comment: They are associated with a pseudo-account. http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-585/ai-questions

Comment: Might be a bit too wordy, but I like the Turing test reference. Seems like a good fit for a chatroom.

Comment: For the past few months I've been using The Nineteenth Byte to make sure I still pass the Turing Test, so a dedicated room would be much appreciated. Erm, I mean, I'm not a bot, of course.

Answer (score 5):

## The Chinese Room

A reference to the [Chinese Room Argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room).

We would need to make it clear that we're separate from [Chinese.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com) though...!

One of the bots could be named Searle, who invented the thought experiment.
Then we really have a Searle getting inputs and producing outputs, just as in the thought experiment.

Answer (score 4):

## **The nth layer**

This would be about deep learning which is about multiple layers of neurons. So, as DL has been very hot in the domain currently, I think this name would be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

**Electric sheep**

I think everyone knows this, just in case: [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F)

Answer (score 4):

### Back Propagation

A reference to backpropagation neural networks. We could use this name because in our chatroom, ideas will be propagated back and forth.

Comment: I think we should avoid names which explicitly reference neural networks. They are not all there is to AI, by far, and anyway, don't we want to discourage overly technical questions? To me it would seem pretty weird to say "sorry, questions about how backpropagation works are off-topic here, go to Data Science", yet have a chatroom literally named "Back Propagation".

Answer (score 3):

## The Thought

> Artificial intelligence is based on the assumption that the process of human **thought** can be mechanized.

Answer (score 2):

## Automata

Study of abstract machines as well as the computational problems that can be solved using them.

Comment: Automata brings to mind mechanical machines, not artificial intelligence. (p.s. I didn't downvote, just explaining a possible reason)

Answer (score 2):

## Searle's Room

Bots: Meta & Cognition

Answer (score 2):

## Replicants

As in Blade Runner. And HAL and Computer for the bots.

Answer (score 1):

#### The early stopping

> Form of regularization used to avoid overfitting when training.

See: [What is early stopping?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/16/8)

Answer (score 0):

## The Dropout

> A technique of reducing overfitting in neural networks. The term "dropout" refers to dropping out units in a neural network.

Comment: I don't think most people would get that reference. I think "college dropout" is what jumps to mind first.